# getting error wile integrating jococo with sonar in ant tasks

Tags: sonarqube, jacoco

I want to use jococco code coverage for my sonar analysis an for that I have downloaded jococo jar and agent jars and also maven plugin jar of jococo, since my project is ant based so I have keep these files in my class path and in ant home lib also now i am using below tags for code coverage in sonar but still i am gettig the error that is ..`Project coverage is set to 0% as no JaCoCo execution data has been dumped:` , please advise how to overcome from this error , FOLKS PLEASE ADVISE

my build xml conating the following tasks for ant in sonar tag shown below..

```
<property key="sonar.java.coveragePlugin" value="jacoco" />
            <property key="sonar.junit.reportsPath" value="${ps}/test-acceptance/com/sfm/ice/oa/report"/> 
              <property key="sonar.jacoco.reportPath" value="${ps}/jacoco/jacoco-ut.exec" /> 
            <property key="sonar.jacoco.itReportPath" value="${ps}/jacoco/jacoco-it.exec" /> 
            <property key="sonar.jacoco.itReportPath" value="${ps}/jacoco/jacoco-it.exec" />
```

and the logs i can see this error as show below ..

```
15:33:31.427 INFO - Retrieve SCM blame information with encoding UTF-8 done: 12742 ms
[20:03:31]15:33:31.431 INFO - Sensor ScmActivitySensor done: 12749 ms
[20:03:31]15:33:31.431 INFO - Sensor CpdSensor...
[20:03:31]15:33:31.432 INFO - SonarEngine is used
[20:03:31]15:33:31.664 INFO - Cross-project analysis disabled
[20:03:40]15:33:40.717 INFO - Sensor CpdSensor done: 9286 ms
[20:03:40]15:33:40.719 INFO - Sensor PmdSensor...
[20:03:40]15:33:40.721 INFO - Execute PMD 4.3...
[20:03:40]15:33:40.737 INFO - Java version: 1.5
[20:03:41]15:33:41.076 INFO - PMD configuration: /opt/app/glacier/buildAgent-8.0.3/work/Glacier/build/pmd.xml
[20:04:24]15:34:24.639 INFO - Execute PMD 4.3 done: 43918 ms
[20:04:24]15:34:24.850 INFO - Sensor PmdSensor done: 44131 ms
[20:04:24]15:34:24.850 INFO - Sensor JaCoCoItSensor...
[20:04:24]15:34:24.856 INFO - Project coverage is set to 0% as no JaCoCo execution data has been dumped: /opt/app/glacier/buildAgent-8.0.3/work/Glacier/${ops}/jacoco/jacoco-it.exec
[20:04:26]15:34:26.203 INFO - No information about coverage per test.
[20:04:26]15:34:26.203 INFO - Sensor JaCoCoItSensor done: 1353 ms
[20:04:26]15:34:26.204 INFO - Sensor JaCoCoOverallSensor...
[20:04:26]15:34:26.204 INFO - Sensor JaCoCoOverallSensor done: 0 ms
[20:04:26]15:34:26.205 INFO - Sensor SurefireSensor...
[20:04:26]15:34:26.206 INFO - parsing /opt/app/glacier/buildAgent-8.0.3/work/Glacier/${ops}/test-acceptance/com/rbsfm/ice/ioa/report
[20:04:26]15:34:26.207 INFO - Sensor SurefireSensor done: 2 ms
[20:04:26]15:34:26.207 INFO - Sensor CheckstyleSensor...
[20:04:26]15:34:26.209 INFO - Execute Checkstyle 5.6...
[20:04:26]15:34:26.218 INFO - Checkstyle configuration: /opt/app/glacier/buildAgent-8.0.3/work/Glacier/build/checkstyle.xml
[20:04:31]15:34:31.581 INFO - Execute Checkstyle 5.6 done: 5372 ms
[20:04:31]15:34:31.586 INFO - Sensor CheckstyleSensor done: 5379 ms
[20:04:31]15:34:31.587 INFO - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor...
[20:04:34]15:34:34.650 INFO - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor done: 3063 ms
[20:04:34]15:34:34.651 INFO - Sensor ProfileSensor...
[20:04:35]15:34:35.308 INFO - Sensor ProfileSensor done: 657 ms
[20:04:35]15:34:35.309 INFO - Sensor ProfileEventsSensor...
[20:04:35]15:34:35.319 INFO - Sensor ProfileEventsSensor done: 10 ms
[20:04:35]15:34:35.320 INFO - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor...
[20:04:35]15:34:35.333 INFO - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor done: 13 ms
[20:04:35]15:34:35.334 INFO - Sensor VersionEventsSensor...
[20:04:35]15:34:35.385 INFO - Sensor VersionEventsSensor done: 51 ms
[20:04:35]15:34:35.386 INFO - Sensor com.headway.plugins.sonar.S101Sensor@3ca021e3...
[20:04:35]15:34:35.415 INFO - Sensor com.headway.plugins.sonar.S101Sensor@3ca021e3 done: 29 ms
[20:04:35]15:34:35.416 INFO - Sensor JaCoCoSensor...
[20:04:35]15:34:35.419 INFO - Project coverage is set to 0% as no JaCoCo execution data has been dumped: /opt/app/hhh/buildAgent-8.0.3/work/hhh/${ops}/jacoco/jacoco-ut.exec
[20:05:14]15:35:14.613 INFO - No information about coverage per test.
[20:05:14]15:35:14.615 INFO - Sensor JaCoCoSensor done: 39199 ms
[20:05:15]15:35:15.444 INFO - Execute decorators...
```

Answer (score 0):

We are successfully using jacoco for unit test coverage with SonarQube, using an Ant build. I can't tell from your snippets whether you are executing unit tests via Ant build, or if you are expecting SonarQube to execute them for you. We have Jenkins execute a build step that executes unit tests (and collects jacoco coverage data) separately and prior to the Jenkins step that executes SonarQube analysis.

That said, it looks like the major difference between what I see in your snippets and what we have in our build.xml is property name: we have sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin, which is not what you are using.

```
<property name="sonar.dynamicAnalysis" value="reuseReports"/>
<property name="sonar.surefire.reportsPath" value="${test.log.dir}"/>
<property name="sonar.junit.reportsPath" value="${test.log.dir}"/>
<property name="sonar.sources" value="${src.dir}" />
<property name="sonar.tests" value="${test.src.dir}" />
<property name="sonar.binaries" value="${classes.dir}" />

<property name="sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin" value="jacoco" />
<property name="sonar.jacoco.reportPath" value="${test.log.dir}/jacoco.exec"/>
```

Buried in our "test" target is this:

```
    <jacoco:coverage enabled="${my.coverage.enabled}" destfile="${test.log.dir}/jacoco.exec">
    <junit printsummary="true"
            fork="yes"
...
    </junit>
    </jacoco:coverage>
</target>
```

Hope that helps.